# Hosting service for PHP REST API and scheduled service

Tags: rest, servicehost, webservicehost

I have implemented REST API using PHP. This API access to MySQL Database.

I was looking for hosting services but I'm not sure where to start, majority of this type of services is referring to Web Hosting, which as I understand is not what I need.

Can anyone suggest any free or cheap service that will support my requirements?
I also need the possibility to schedule service which will periodically access REST API. This one is not implemented yet, because I'm not sure what kind of languages/frameworks are usually supported by the hosting service.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the database itself hosted or just the PHP? If the latter, most any web host with PHP will do what you desire. If the former, you'll need a database host as well as a web host.

Comment: I think I'll need both. 
I owe Web Hosting domain and service on FatCow, but I'm not sure and I can't find any information regarding hosting of Web API's. 
Do you know if there is any way to schedule a service which will run periodically on this kind of hosting services? And what kind of languages do they usually support?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think that a regular web hosting account would actually work just fine for what you need.  If you think about it, the only difference between your RESTful API and any other website is that your API does not return HTML, but rather returns data that is encoded to be consumed by another program instead of a human user directly.  From a hosting perspective, though... there really is no difference.  There are lots of companies that provide PHP/MySQL hosting out there - for example, [Dreamhost](http://dreamhost.com/).  Lots and lots of options.

Comment: Do you know if these hosting services allow to have scheduled service which will run periodically? Thank you.

Comment: I am able to schedule cron jobs on dreamhost.  I haven't needed to do so, therefore I don't have personal experience on doing it there, but I know that it's possible right from the account control panel.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the hosting provider supports HTTP requests like DELETE,PUT,etc and you are using them in your REST application/service then you are good to go. So just ask for a confirmation about this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need php  + MySQL hosting then go for web hosting

And for shedule service you can use cron jobs

In cron job u can select an php script and interval of running it automatically

It will automatically execute after given interval of time